# MiniKubeerror in validating replica set:ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.metadata):unknown field"spec" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1

Tags: nginx, yaml, minikube, replicaset

I use minikube and below is the sample Yaml file. I get the below error while try to create the pods.

```
$ kubectl create -f nginx-rs.yml 
error: error validating "nginx-rs.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.metadata): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Here is my YAML file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-rs
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
     name: nginx-pod
     labels:
       app: nginx-app
       tier: frontend
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: nginx-container
         image: nginx
         ports:
         - containerport: 80
```

I cross checked my YAML with [this tool](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/) and everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

The template `spec` is nested under `metadata` instead of the template itself.

Just move `spec` one indentation back to be nested under template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-rs
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
     name: nginx-pod
     labels:
       app: nginx-app
       tier: frontend
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: nginx-container
       image: nginx
```

Side note: It might be best to use [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) instead of the `ReplicaSet` to avoid conflicts with the ports. The `Deployment` object automatically creates the `ReplicaSet` controlling the pods in the `spec`.

Comment: This worked. I always use deployment for production env. I was just playing around with minikube and missed the indentation.